# HBase Cluster- Can't connect to hbase via phoenix client

Tags: hbase, high-availability, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect HBase cluster via Phoenix. First, I have copied Phoenix client and query server jars files to HMaster and HRegion lib folder and restarted HBase services.

Server - Started the Phoenix server via /bin/queryserver.py. Its running properly.

Client - 
`AvaticaClientRuntimeException: Remote driver error: RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "http://hacluster:8764".`

[log details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7mk1.png)

Hbase-site.xml file configuration for High availabilty cluster

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.master</name>
  <value>activenamenode:60000</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name> 
  <value>hdfs://hacluster/HBase</value>
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name> 
  <value>true</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name> 
  <value>zk1,zk2,zk3</value> 
</property> 
<property> <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name> 
  <value>60000</value>
<property>
```

Its working on pseudo node cluster. But fails in HA enabled Hadoop cluster.

In HA Cluster, i have set active namenode url instead of HA nameservice for `hbase.rootdir` property in `hbase-site.xml` file.

Comment: Hi did you sort out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is listed in the error message: `No suitable driver found for http...`. Somehow, you're using an HTTP connection string. I don't know how Avatica works specifically, but I'm assuming you want a JDBC connection string which is the most common way to connect to something like Phoenix.

For instance:
`jdbc:phoenix:m1.hdp.local,m2.hdp.local,d1.hdp.local:2181:/hbase-unsecure`

See https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HADOOP/pages/11993090/Phoenix+JDBC+Client+Setup for more details.